# Como puedo traer un atributo de un objeto de JSON para poder generar un CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

Me encuentro absorbiendo una *API* y puedo traer la información de los diccionarios principales de la *API*, sin embargo cuando intento traer un archivo fuera de ese diccionario, me arroja un error indicando que la *key* consultada no existe.

¿Alguien podrÍa apoyarme con este problema?  Les comparto mi código

```
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    prod_list = response.json()['productos'] 
    
    with open('prod.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=['producto_id','modelo', 'total_existencia', 'titulo', 'sat_key', 'img_portada','link_privado','precio_1'])
        writer.writeheader()

        for prod in prod_list:
            writer.writerow({
                'producto_id' : prod['producto_id'],
                'modelo' : prod['modelo'],
                'total_existencia' : prod ['total_existencia'],
                'titulo' : prod['titulo'],
                'sat_key' : prod['sat_key'],
                'img_portada' : prod['img_portada'],
                'link_privado' : prod['link_privado'],
                'precio_1' : prod['precio_1']
            })

else:
    print(f'Error de carga {response.status_code}')
```

Comment: Quizá el json devuelto por la api no es como esperas (ejemplo, un json con un mensaje de error). Probaste mostrar en consola el contenido de dicho antes de mandar los datos al csv?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas explorar API y JSON de una respuesta, tambien el documentación de API. Si la key no existe, entonces, haces algo no correcto con API o la key no tiene que existir. Proba usar `breakpoint()` para explorar una respuesta.